# How to make libsqlite3.dylib work in Swift in xCode project?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am trying to make the sqlite library work in my Swift project in xCode 6.3.

When I try to use it in code I get the following error:

[image]

I have added the library in my project like so:

[image]

And I have imported it in the bridging header like this:

[image]

The sqlite function calls do autocomplete so it seems like it is added properly, but it still gives me the error of undefined symbols...

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to use sqlite3.dylib in a Swift project by doing the following:

I created the bridging header. I created a wrapper objective-c class.

In the bridging header I then imported both  and my custom wrapper header.

Because in my bridging header I imported my custom sqlite wrapper now my swift code can access the methods I exposed in its header.

So, the point is that my objective-c wrapper can access the sqlite3.dylib, and because I import the wrapper class in the bridging header my Swift code can then use it.

So, Swift cannot access the sqlite3.dylib c code directly, but my objective-c code can, which works as the "middle guy" between sqlite3.dylib and Swift code.

Answer (score 1):

If you want database connection in swift then use sqlite.swift library it is easier than sqlite3.dylb
here is procedure how to use it click [Here](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md)

Comment: I'll take a look at the project you mentioned here. Although this does not answer the question, thanks for pointing out different option.

Comment: if you want any help about sqlite.swift then i will happy to help you and sorry for that i have less knowledge of sqlite3.dylb library